Novel in which aliens use transporter technology to copy humans and then torture them
I read a sci-fi novel a few years back, but I can't remember who it's by or what it's called.
In the story, humans have developed matter transporters so that humans can be teleported from place to place. However, a war with aliens has broken out and the aliens have captured some of these transporters. They realise that human patterns are still held in them and are able to "print" limitless copies of these humans, which they do. They then torture these copies in various ways.
The story is mainly about a man who is one of these copies.

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

Within the last ten years, I'd say, and I read it on my phone so I've no idea about the cover.

Not a novel, but this reminds me of the Gatekeepers in the Schlock Mercenary webcomic.

Thanks, but it was definitely a book, not a comic.

The Resurrected Man by Sean Williams has a human serial killer who does this.

Is it one of Wil McCarthy's novels?

I.... don't think so - sorry!

This might be a duplicate of this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82626/human-agent-trapped-by-aliens-and-trying-to-escape

Sounds like something the Drukhari would do in Warhammer 40K.

Possibly The Other End of Time, by Frederik Pohl? Wikipedia says that it follows a man called Dan Dannerman, along with a small group of people, who  are transported through space after entering the Starlab space station.

The humans then learn that they are just copies of their old bodies; their real bodies were sent back to the Earth with wiped memories. Other copies have been experimented on with vivisection.

Found based on the accepted answer to this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/ty35js/scifi_book_where_aliens_capture_people_and/
